# How do I write a stream to a pipe on a remote machine

Tags: command-line, remote, pipe, suse

The below command works for file. But I see it doesn't work for a pipe

```
echo 'Some Text' | ssh user@remotehost "cat > /remotefile.txt"
```

I need to do `tail -f` of a pipe and want it to be written to another pipe on a remote machine?

Comment: I am using "suse linux"

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question. The purpose can be achieved with the below command. On host1 do:

```
ssh user@host2 "tail -f /tmp/pipe"
```